# Difference between ADT and Classes?

Tags: c, data-structures, abstract-data-type

```
ADT is the set of operations. ADT's are mathematical abstractions.
```

Does this mean that ADT are same as classes or am i confusing both together ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key to the difference is **abstract**. Think of an ADT more like an interface - a class with only method declarations, no implementation details.

As an example, a Stack ADT defines the basic stack operations like push and pop (but says nothing of how these operations should be implemented), while a Stack class would use either a linked-list or an array to actually implement these operations.

Comment: Ok. So the Stack class will be my data structures + object-oriented concepts that I use for implementation like a linked list or an array.
But, when we import a package with all its classes, aren't the implementation hidden from the user importing the package? Wouldn't that make class names as ADTs too?  I hope my question is clear.

Comment: @Bernhard But, Why can't a class be considered as an ADT ?

Comment: @SMVaidhyanathan Once you have a concrete implementation, it's by definition no longer abstract (and thus can't be an abstract data type). It's like the difference between a list of properties (like texture, what it looks like and what it's made of) that defines what ice cream is (which would be like an ADT) and a recipe for how to make a particular type of ice cream (which would be like the class). The actual ice cream would be like the object.

Comment: @subinsahayam The fact that you can call one of the methods of a class or one of its objects and it would behave in a certain way arguably means it's no longer abstract. The implementation details are still there, and it affects how the class and its objects behaves and possibly what other methods it has, even if you can't directly see the implementation details.

Answer (score 10):

According to Code Complete, ADT is a collection of data and operations that work on that data.

Example for ADT:

List

- Initialize list
- Insert item in list
- Remove item from list
- Read next item from list

ADT form the foundation for the concept of classes. In languages that support classes, you can implement each abstract data type as its own class. **Classes** usually involve the additional concepts of **inheritance and polymorphism**. One way of thinking of a class is as an abstract data type plus inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: This should be the selected correct answer!

Answer (score 3):

An abstract data type (ADT) is a mathematical abstraction of a real world thing and can be implemented in a concrete data type in different languages.

An ADT defines operations for the given type and mathematically expresses their behaviour.
Concrete implementations of an ADT can differ from each other. In that way classes are implementing the ADT and methods implement operations.

Classes have a slightly different terminology than ADTs and add other characteristics, like:

- they for example may live in *packages*
- their members are called *attributes* and *methods*
- attributes and methods have a certain *visibility* constraint

And methods:

- can be *abstract*, too. but then, their behaviour isn't defined - only their *method signature* - an inheriting concrete class must provide an implementation

Don't confuse abstract data types with *abstract classes* in a concrete language.

Answer (score 0):

A class is an implementation of an abstract data type (ADT).

Answer (score -1):

**ADTs are the way of classifying data structure by providing a minimal expected interface and set of Method**

ADT's = set of values + Operation
Example Stack, Queue

Comment: You mean "a set of *types*"?